# How to use Google Sheets to categorise data, depending on text values in a column

Tags: google-sheets-formula, text-classification, categorization

I ask this, as I previously performed this task using Python. I'm moving on to a new position and I need to pass this task over to someone who does not know how to program.

I am hoping there is a simple and suitable Formula to use on Google Sheets.

in the following table on Google Sheets:

[image]

Is there a **formula I could use to automatically categorise that data?**

ie in pseudocode

---

If Column A contains "password" or "sign in":

Column B = "Account Access"

Else If

Column A contains "support" or "contact":

Column B = "Customer Support"

---

Etc for multiple other categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use REGEXMATCH:

```
=IFS(REGEXMATCH(A1, "password|sign in"),"Account Access",
     REGEXMATCH(A1, "support|customer"),"Customer Support",
     TRUE,"other")
```

Expand as needed.